# Reflected XSS issue in Salesforce Visualforce Page

Tags: visualforce, javascript

I'm facing Reflected XSS issues for the below 2 lines in Visualforce Page . I have tried by keeping JSENCODE/URLENCODE to fix the issue but functionlity is breaking . Could anyone suggest for the below VF page .

- `top.location.href = '{!redir}';`-- issue in this line
- `window.location.assign('{!redir}');` -- issue in this line

## VF Page :

```
<apex:page standardController="Quote__c" extensions="QuoteOverview" recordSetVar="Quote">
<apex:includeScript value="/support/console/42.0/integration.js"/>
    <script>
        var hostname = "https://" + window.location.hostname.toLowerCase(); 
        var quoteStatus ='{!QuoteStatus}';
        var isArchived ='{!IsArchived}'; 
        var opptyId = '{!JSENCODE(OpptyID)}';
        function isLightningDesktop() {
          return( "{!$User.UIThemeDisplayed }" == "Theme4d");
        }

        /** Function to close tab to avoid infinite loop in lightning - Start (Angela, 03/13/2018)**/
            function CloseTab() {
            sforce.console.getEnclosingPrimaryTabId(closeSubtab);
        }

        var closeSubtab = function closeSubtab(result) {
            var tabId = result.id;
            sforce.console.closeTab(tabId);
        };
        /** Function to close tab to avoid infinite loop in lightning - End (Angela, 03/13/2018)**/

        console.log('isArchived='+isArchived);
        if (isArchived == 'true') {
            top.location.href = hostname + "/apex/Quote_Archived?opptyId="+opptyId;
        }else{
            if(quoteStatus == "true"){
                alert('Quote on this opportunity has been deleted');
            }
            console.log('else'); 
            if(isLightningDesktop()){
                console.log('==1==>'+'{!redir}');   
                top.location.href = '{!redir}';

                //function call to close tab to avoid infinite loop - (Angela, 03/13/2018) 
                CloseTab();
            }else{
                console.log('==2==>'+'{!redir}');
                window.location.assign('{!redir}');
            }
        }
    </script>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: top window manipulation is not a good approach. You try usingthe openPrimaryTab() and closetab